# Arduino NANO and external eemprom issue

Tags: arduino, external, arduino-ide, eeprom, nano

I'm trying to connect EEPROM chip [24LC01B](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/545714/MICROCHIP/24LC01B-I/P.html) to Arduino Nano 328P, write data to it, read and display it in Serial Monitor.

Serial Monitor shows only

> Writing...
> Reading...

I can't figure out what the problem is.

```
#include <Wire.h>

#define memoryAddr 0x50
byte in=0x00;

void setup()
{
  Wire.begin(); // join i2c bus (address optional for master)
  Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop()
{
  Serial.println("Writing...");
  
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x50); // This is the 24LC01B device address
  Wire.write(0x0);               // Start writing at address 0
  Wire.write("Hell");            // Send 4 bytes
  Wire.endTransmission();       
  delay(100);                    // Without a short delay, the EEPROM is still
                                // writing when you start to write the next block
                                // Feel free to experiment with the delay length
  
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x50);
  Wire.write(0x4);               // Write next four bytes starting at address 4
  Wire.write("o Wo");
  Wire.endTransmission();     
  delay(100);
  

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x50);
  Wire.write(0x8);               // Write last four bytes starting at address 8
  Wire.write("rld!");
  Wire.endTransmission();     
  delay(100);

  Serial.println("Reading...");

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x50); // Now we're going to read it back
  Wire.write(0x0);               // Sending address 0, so it knows where we'll want
  Wire.endTransmission();       // to read from

  Wire.requestFrom(0x50,12);    // Start new transmission and keep reading for 12 bytes
  while(Wire.available())    
  { 
    char c = Wire.read();    // Read a byte and write it out to the Serial port
    Serial.print(c);         
  } 
  Serial.println();

  delay(5000);
}
```

Here is how I've connected it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8EFc.jpg

Comment: Have you checked what endTransmission() return?

Comment: @Nino, I've changed the last part of the code:

`Wire.endTransmission();
  int x = Wire.endTransmission(); Serial.println(x, DEC);
  Serial.println("Done");`

and got a value of 2, which should mean "received NACK on transmit of address".

I'll try to google it, but I'd be grateful if someone could help figure it out as well.

Comment: Call endTransmission only once!

Comment: @Nino
OK, the last part of my code now looks like this. 

`Serial.println("Reading...");

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x50);
  Wire.write(0x0);        
  int x = Wire.endTransmission(); 
  Serial.println(x, DEC);   
  Serial.println("Done");

  delay(5000);
}`
Am I getting the return value correctly?

Comment: This looks right. What are you getting?

Comment: @Nino I'm receiving 2, which is NACK, I believe. I haven't yet figured out how to proceed with this issue.